# How to allow all users to read only certain documents with a field " friend : true "

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In Firestore i have the collection as "users" and document id are random numbers.

Now i need to allow the users to read the documents which contains field **friend : true**

I have tried following rules :

```
match /users/{document=**}
{
allow read : if request.resource.data.friend = true;
}


match /users/{document=**}
        {
        allow read : if resource.data.friend = true;
        }
```

But yet i can't read the documents which contains friend = true.

Please help me

Comment: Security rules by themselves don't do anything.  They only take effect when paired with a query that triggers them.  Please edit the question to show the app code that doesn't work the way you expect with these rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that you're not passing the same condition in with the read operation. Keep in mind that [Firebase security rules do not filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters). Instead they "merely" ensure that the read operation is allowed. So the second rules in your snippet allow this query:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("users").where("friend", "=", true)
```

If you don't pass the `where` condition, the read will be rejected as you're trying to read all documents, which the security rules don't allow. Only when the query and the rules match up, will the read be allowed.

---

Your first rules fragment cannot work in any case, as `request.resource` only has meaning in the context of write operations. From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#resource):

> `request.resource`
>
> The new resource value, present on write requests only.

Comment: Wow exactly you are correct. It worked as i needed. Thanks alot.